# Change span text referring to parent href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I'm looking to change the text on span, but I couldn't target by class nor ID, as they have the same classes, the only difference I spot is the parent link href attribute,
Is there a way I can target them?

[image: Code I'm looking to change]

Comment: Please copy & paste the code in to the question, not an image of it. We can't edit the code in an image to show you the correct approach. To do what you require you could select the `span` elements from their text using [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) or by the `href` attribute on the `a` using an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector).

Comment: pls see if this help: https://jsfiddle.net/KennyChoy/eub8y0gf/

Comment: You can use any of: an attribute selector `[href='..']` / a class selector with `.eq(n)` / a `.filter` with `.text()=="Customers"` / a `:contains("Customers")` selector - each depends on other navigation texts and how precise you need it to be.   All of which have existing answers on SO or can be extracted from [learn.jquery.com](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)

Answer (score 1):

Although you could select from the actual text (Customers, Products etc) as this is what will be changed it would only work first time and we aren't told whether the change may need to take place more than once.

A more reliable way would be to select on the hrefs and their ultimate strings.

In CSS this can be done using the $ sign. For example:

```
a[href$="Customers"]
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

You add more to this to ensure you target only items in that list.